# Simple effects on Monogame

Tags: windows-phone, effects, monogame

I'm a beginner in MonoGame development, and I try to develop a memory game for mobile,for doing that, I want to make some effects  like flipping  an  image, page curling,...

Some advice/tutorials to start please?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get in touch with monogame shader effects you should first read this article:
https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Effects-And-Shaders

Generaly you could easily port shaders made for XNA.
There is some curling shader but it seems it has to be ported to monogame:
[Could a vertex shader be used for a page turn effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783446/could-a-vertex-shader-be-used-for-a-page-turn-effect/21834412#21834412)

As i remember correctly you have to use **vs_4_0_level_9_1** or **ps_4_0_level_9_1** for the compile directive in the shader on Win8 mobile. Like this:

`technique MyTechnique
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 main();
    }
}`

PS: You can flip texture using **SpriteEffects** parameter in **SpriteBatch::Draw()** method call.